# PHP XSL:key 'match' pattern compliation failed

Tags: php, xslt

I have the following key but get an apache error when I try to run the code.

```
<xsl:key name="dt" match="//eprint[substring(date,1,4) &gt;= $year]" use="substring(date,1,4)" />
```

The error I get is:

```
[Thu Jul 12 10:51:18.724468 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 24089] [client 127.0.0.1:34808] PHP Warning:  XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): Forbidden variable in /home/david/Documents/staffpub/inc/staff.php on line 54, referer: http://localhost:81/test_jsonp.html
[Thu Jul 12 10:51:18.724614 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 24089] [client 127.0.0.1:34808] PHP Warning:  XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: file /home/david/Documents/staffpub/inc/sorts/year.xsl line 5 element key in /home/david/Documents/staffpub/inc/staff.php on line 54, referer: http://localhost:81/test_jsonp.html
[Thu Jul 12 10:51:18.724634 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 24089] [client 127.0.0.1:34808] PHP Warning:  XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): xsl:key : 'match' pattern compilation failed '//eprint[substring(date,1,4) &gt;= $year]' in /home/david/Documents/staffpub/inc/staff.php on line 54, referer: http://localhost:81/test_jsonp.html
[Thu Jul 12 10:51:18.732938 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 24089] [client 127.0.0.1:34808] PHP Warning:  XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): No stylesheet associated to this object in /home/david/Documents/staffpub/inc/staff.php on line 59, referer: http://localhost:81/test_jsonp.html
```

I guess there is something wrong with the key set up, but I am unsure what.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

A sample data set is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<eprints xmlns='http://eprints.org/ep2/data/2.0'>
  <eprint id='http://dsfdsfs'>
   <eprintid>3424243242423</eprintid>
   <date>2012-12</date>
  </eprint>
```

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using? If it is one that only supports XSLT 1.0 then it is an error to use a variable reference in the "match" (or "use") attribute in xsl:key.

Comment: How do I find out what process I am using? I didnt write this code, trying to resolve an issue with it :( 
I am using libxslt Version  1.1.29 if that helps?

Comment: libxslt is the XSLT processor.....(Although for future reference, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr). But in anycase, I believe libxslt only supports XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Hi, thanks. So I changes the key to be a value rather than a variable and it works. Is it not possible to pass a variable into a key?

Comment: Not in XSLT 1.0. You will have to change to use an XSLT 2.0 (or better still XSLT 3.0) processor, like Saxon.